# How to convert HTML table to array with golang

Tags: html, go, goquery

I'm having a problem trying to convert an HTML table into a Golang array. I've tried to achieve it using x/net/html and goquery, without any success on both of them.

Let's say we have this HTML table:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, Content 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Content 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, Content 3</td>
        <td>Row 1, Content 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Content 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Content 2</td>
        <td>Row 2, Content 3</td>
        <td>Row 2, Content 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I'd like to end up with this array:

```
------------------------------------
|Row 1, Content 1| Row 1, Content 2|
------------------------------------
|Row 2, Content 1| Row 2, Content 2|
------------------------------------
```

As you guy can see, I'm just ignoring Contents 3 and 4.

My extraction code:

```
func extractValue(content []byte) {
  doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(bytes.NewReader(content))

  doc.Find("table tr td").Each(func(i int, td *goquery.Selection) {
    // ...
  })
}
```

I've tried to add a controller number which would be responsible for ignoring the `<td>` that I don't want to convert and calling

```
td.NextAll()
```

but with no luck. Do you guys have any idea of what should I do to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the actual code you used?

Comment: The html table doesn't look valid. There's no closing td tags here if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get away with package `golang.org/x/net/html` only.

```
var body = strings.NewReader(`                                                                                                                            
        <html>                                                                                                                                            
        <body>                                                                                                                                            
        <table>                                                                                                                                           
        <tr>                                                                                                                                              
        <td>Row 1, Content 1</td>                                                                                                                          
        <td>Row 1, Content 2</td>                                                                                                                          
        <td>Row 1, Content 3</td>                                                                                                                          
        <td>Row 1, Content 4</td>                                                                                                                          
        </tr>                                                                                                                                             
        <tr>                                                                                                                                              
        <td>Row 2, Content 1</td>                                                                                                        
        <td>Row 2, Content 2</td>                                                                                                                          
        <td>Row 2, Content 3</td>                                                                                                                          
        <td>Row 2, Content 4</td>                                                                                                                          
        </tr>  
        </table>                                                                                                                                          
        </body>                                                                                                                                           
        </html>`)          

func main() {
    z := html.NewTokenizer(body)
    content := []string{}

    // While have not hit the </html> tag
    for z.Token().Data != "html" {
        tt := z.Next()
        if tt == html.StartTagToken {
            t := z.Token()
            if t.Data == "td" {
                inner := z.Next()
                if inner == html.TextToken {
                    text := (string)(z.Text())
                    t := strings.TrimSpace(text)
                    content = append(content, t)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Print to check the slice's content
    fmt.Println(content)
}
```

This code is written only for this typical HTML pattern only, but refactoring it to be more general wouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thank you very much. After changing a little your code I got the result expected. https://play.golang.org/p/zykOWwHCcG

Comment: @DanilloSouza happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more structured way of extracting data from HTML Tables, https://github.com/nfx/go-htmltable does support the row/colspans.

```
type AM4 struct {
    Model             string `header:"Model"`
    ReleaseDate       string `header:"Release date"`
    PCIeSupport       string `header:"PCIesupport[a]"`
    MultiGpuCrossFire bool   `header:"Multi-GPU CrossFire"`
    MultiGpuSLI       bool   `header:"Multi-GPU SLI"`
    USBSupport        string `header:"USBsupport[b]"`
    SATAPorts         int    `header:"Storage features SATAports"`
    RAID              string `header:"Storage features RAID"`
    AMDStoreMI        bool   `header:"Storage features AMD StoreMI"`
    Overclocking      string `header:"Processoroverclocking"`
    TDP               string `header:"TDP"`
    SupportExcavator  string `header:"CPU support[14] Excavator"`
    SupportZen        string `header:"CPU support[14] Zen"`
    SupportZenPlus    string `header:"CPU support[14] Zen+"`
    SupportZen2       string `header:"CPU support[14] Zen 2"`
    SupportZen3       string `header:"CPU support[14] Zen 3"`
    Architecture      string `header:"Architecture"`
}
am4Chipsets, _ := htmltable.NewSliceFromURL[AM4]("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_chipsets")
fmt.Println(am4Chipsets[2].Model)
fmt.Println(am4Chipsets[2].SupportZen2)

// Output:
// X370
// Varies[c]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try an approach like this to make a 2d array and handle variable row sizes:

```golang
    z := html.NewTokenizer(body)
    table := [][]string{}
    row := []string{}

    for z.Token().Data != "html" {
        tt := z.Next()
        if tt == html.StartTagToken {
            t := z.Token()

            if t.Data == "tr" {
                if len(row) > 0 {
                    table = append(table, row)
                    row = []string{}
                }
            }

            if t.Data == "td" {
                inner := z.Next()

                if inner == html.TextToken {
                    text := (string)(z.Text())
                    t := strings.TrimSpace(text)
                    row = append(row, t)
                }
            }

        }
    }
    if len(row) > 0 {
        table = append(table, row)
    }
```